# How long do you wait before re-flagging a post for moderator review?

Tags: support, moderation, flags, best-practices

Since there is no way to tell if a moderator did something other than to see it done (no email notification), how long do I wait for the fix before flagging the post again?

In the specific case that got me wondering I accidentally hit the upvote instead of the flag on a comment, and need it reversed, but I expect there are other situations where one would need to check whether a flagged situation got taken care of.

Answer (score 4):

You can't 'reflag' a moderator on a post. The moderator flag is a one time only flag.

Otherwise though, I would simply email one of the mods and ask them to look into it.
Whether the matter is urgent or not is a whole different thing that must be taken on a case by case basis.

Comment: You can issue the "Requires Moderator Attention" more than once?

Comment: No, you can't.

Comment: Ah. I stand educated - thanks :)

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: I got educated once, but it went away after a few months.

Comment: I got vaccinated so I never have to worry about getting an education ever again.

Comment: My vaccination hasn't arrived that.  Will I be getting it soon?  Otherwise someone will insist that I get some sort of education soon.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's any need to reflag at all. If no action was taken, it was either unread or denied.

Comment: But there's no way to determine if the ball got dropped.

Comment: Maybe the flag could act more like a support ticket. You could view the flags you've submitted and see what the response was.

Comment: Things are often handled privately in emails, there is not always a need for a user to know whether their report has been received.

Comment: I agree with Rich and Jon here. Submit a flag, and then let it go. No need to check up on flag-submissions. The admins definitely want to keep the site working properly, and will take care of issues as they see fit and at their convenience.

Comment: With as many mods as there are per site, it is very hard for me to believe that the ball ever gets "dropped". If a mod feels action needs to be taken, he/she will take it. If they don't think action should, they will either kill the flag or leave it for someone else to make the call.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding the case you mentioned (accidentally up voting), you can just click the up arrow again to remove your up vote.

Comment: No you can't. Not on a comment.

Comment: Damn! Didn't mean to do that. Oh well.

Comment: @Rich B: You're right - sorry, I missed the fact that the OP was asking about voting on a comment.