# Allow users to flag questions more than once

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags

EDIT 3:
Looks like this may be `[status-completed]`... see [this answer by Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61916/once-a-flag-is-cleared-from-the-mod-queue-the-same-post-cannot-be-re-flagged/61930#61930).

> EDIT 2:
>   This used to be titled "Why can you only flag a given post for mod attention once?"  I changed the title because I morphed the post into a feature request.  The body of the question, on the other hand, already illustrated the rationale, so no change there.

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19109/how-long-do-you-wait-before-re-flagging-a-post-for-moderator-review/19111#19111), users can only flag a given post for moderator attention one time ("*The moderator flag is a one time only flag.*").  What's the reason for that?  It seems to me that the following could occur:

1. User A flags post for mod attention
2. Mod looks at post, maybe takes an action, clears post from mod queue
3. User B edits post and introduces a new problem
4. User A attempts to flag post again, but attempt fails

Why shouldn't user A be able to re-flag the post?  Would the attempt to re-flag be met with an active error message or a silent failure?  In the latter case, the user might not even know to use the backup "e-mail the staff" approach to notify a mod.

EDIT 1: According to @random♦:

> Tested, even mods are only allowed one flag a post.

There isn't much opining going on, but it seems like all of it is pro-change.  So, adding the feature-request tag.

Comment: I remember flagging twice a question for moderator's attention, recently. I don't remember it failing, but I could be wrong. Who will test it on this question?

Comment: An attempted re-flag gives an error message saying "you've already flagged this post" *after* you hit Submit (which is somewhat annoying since it should have said so earlier before I typed my message). At least when you flag for mod attention. I don't know about the other two types, but I assume they're the same.

Comment: next step... **THE SUPERFLAG**

Comment: Doneded: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61916/once-a-flag-is-cleared-from-the-mod-queue-the-same-post-cannot-be-re-flagged

Answer (score 4):

There is a flag "queue" that holds posts with flags on them. Many users can flag a post, but you can't submit more then one flag per post.

When a moderator checks the post / takes action, they also clear the flag from signalling itself.

This, however, doesn't allow you to flag the post again, even if something went wrong (e.g.: botched edit job) and you will be shown the error that you have already flagged the post:

> You have already flagged this post for moderator attention

Comment: See, that's exactly what I would think.  But the post I linked to specifically says that's __not__ the behavior that's actually used.

Comment: Well someone will have to test it. What happened to [Geoffrey Chetwood](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5640/geoffrey-chetwood) anyway?

Comment: Tested, even mods are only allowed one flag a post.

Comment: He's banned on all sites now.  Maybe he still hangs out in the IRC channel?

Comment: I actually hate that @random, I like IMing other mods through flags :P