# Should I be able to flag a post for moderation more than once, after first issue has been dealt with?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderation, flags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013209/how-to-stop-c-compile-on-first-error-in-vs-2010-vs-2008-macros-dont-work/3013240) incorrectly got closed as duplicate.  I voted to reopen, but rather than wait for the required numbers to pass by and agree to reopen, I flagged it and asked for it to be reopened.

Meanwhile the OP re-asked the question, and got an answer.  Someone noticed this, and has voted to close it again, as it is now a duplicate (of a different question than last time).  I agree, so voted to close again.  Again, rather than wait for the votes on an old question, I tried to flag it so a mod could close it.  But it won't let me, as I have already flagged it.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46472/why-can-you-only-flag-a-given-post-for-mod-attention-once) asks basically the same thing as I'm asking, but doesn't explain why, once a mod has dealt with the first issue, the flags can't be cleared so that you can re assign for mods attention a second time.

Comment: Rel: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46472/allow-users-to-flag-questions-more-than-once and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61916/once-a-flag-is-cleared-from-the-mod-queue-the-same-post-cannot-be-re-flagged/61930#61930