# Should users be allowed to post comments in a question where they've posted deleted offensive comments before?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, flags, offensive

I recently came across an old question where a sexist comment was posted. Flagging the comment, plus comments containing personal attacks made when I criticised the comment, didn't resolve the situation, only flagging the question itself for moderator attention fixed it. The offensive comment, my responses, and his follow-ups were deleted.

Except that now he's posted the exact same sexist comment in the exact same question [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72312/how-should-i-capitalize-perl). Flagging the comment hasn't done anything, and I won't be able to flag the question for moderator attention again [due to this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61916/once-a-flag-is-cleared-from-the-mod-queue-the-same-post-cannot-be-re-flagged). The only option would be to email the support team itself.

Why should this user be allowed to post comments again in a question where they've had comments deleted for being offensive?

Comment: I'm starting to get the sense that I'm something of a fascist. In my view, that question, like this comment, is entirely OT. I'm surprised that I had to cast the opening "off-topic" vote.

Comment: "This comment" being your comment, or the comment I was complaining about? Also, would the Perl question be suitable for the programmers stack exchange?

Comment: It wasn't sexist, it was offensive.  I've added my flag to the pile.

Comment: Ah...middle school humor! But Lance has it right, the comment is not sexist as such, though the poster might be. It is inappropriate, however. Flagged, and it disappeared.

Comment: I was referring to the comment that I made, it not having anything to do with the question. I'm not sure if it would be suitable for the programmers stack exchange. I haven't really hung out there much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not a big fan of further censoring users.  People can change and learn from their mistakes.

As it currently stands, a user will continue to have comment posting abilities even after a comment deletion.  The question "lock" feature might be used by a moderator to freeze a question in some circumstances.  There is also the "delete comments" we use sometimes, but not often.

A user will become noticed by moderators if they attract multiple flags and a lot of attention to themself.  From there, moderators can decide if any other action is needed or required to keep order.

I believe as it stands, there are sufficient tools in place for users to flag and remove comments.  Moderators also have their own array of tools to help keep the site clean and orderly.  I don't think we need any further options as it currently stands.  I am open to hearing other opinions and options though from other users/mods.