# Remember delete votes

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

When a duplicate or poor question get closed and the question at its whole own doesn't add any value to the community, I tend to immediately click `delete`. Everytime it tells me that I can cast the vote after 2 days. Apart from the fact that it's annoying (why would you ever show an useless link in the UI?), it doesn't even **remember** the vote (actually, I discovered that today). The 10K tools also doesn't show anywhere a listing of closed questions which are *really* eligible for deleting. I would have to keep track of all those questions myself so that I can vote after 2 days (which I wouldn't).

I would suggest to either let that `delete` link actually remember the vote or at least make this link disappear as long as the logged-in user couldn't cast the vote anyway and then add an overview of closed-questions-eligible-for-delete to the 10K tools.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72181/allow-faster-deleting-of-obviously-bad-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20K users can [now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/propose-a-new-20k-reputation-privilege/70009#70009) immediately cast a delete vote on closed questions. I am happy with this.

Answer (score 4):

Re the last paragraph, I've committed some tweaks such that:

- the delete button won't show up unless you can *actually* vote for it
- the 10k tools /tools/recently-closed screen shows the date it was closed
- posts that you can't (yet) vote to delete are dimmed

Since this screen will now be [sorted by closed date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72569/show-and-sort-recently-closed-posts-list-by-close-time-not-post-time) it should be pretty easy to see where you can start obliterating.

Of course, if something is **obviously** in need of deletion, please feel free to flag for moderator attention - see [Jeff's reply here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72181/allow-faster-deleting-of-obviously-bad-questions/72190#72190)