# 10K tool request: newly available for deletion

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

Using the 10K tools, I can see newly closed questions, newly deleted questions, and questions with delete votes. What would be useful, though, is questions that have only recently become eligible for deletion. (Newly closed questions don't do the trick, because there is a waiting period).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72541/remember-delete-votes See Marc's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually just go back a couple of days in [the "recently closed" list](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/recently-closed?page=20) and have a pretty good chance of finding questions eligible for deletion.

Keep mind though that not *everything* that gets closed should be deleted. [Exercise particular restraint when dealing with questions closed as *duplicates*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates).

Comment: Questions in the "recently closed" list, that are **not** eligible for deletion, are dimmed. Go back a dozen pages or so, and you'll see non-dimmed question titles - these are eligible for deletion (users with 10k-20k rep may delete questions two days after they're closed). I second Shog9's comments on restraint, though.