# Can't re-flag posts undeleted by user

Tags: discussion, flags, moderators, undelete

I noticed the flag weight has become a link to a page that lets you view your flagging history (has this been announced?). I trawled through the first few pages, curious to see the results of my flagging. I noticed a few posts which a mod deleted, which the user then proceeded to undelete:

- [A question about charset encoding and ICU4C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218251/a-question-about-charset-encoding-and-icu4c/5244078#5244078)
- [Handle VerifyError: Error #1014 when loading swfs using AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263166/handle-verifyerror-error-1014-when-loading-swfs-using-as3/5244062#5244062)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453757/cannot-connect-to-a-modified-bundled-and-registered-amazon-ami/5213323#5213323
- [How to compile for older 3dsmax versions with 2010 \ 2011 sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422095/how-to-compile-for-older-3dsmax-versions-with-2010-2011-sdk/5209874#5209874)

In one of the above cases (I've also seen another, but can't find it again), the user posted a comment asking why the post was deleted. Unfortunately the mod probably never got notified of this comment.

Big problem here - I cannot reflag any of these posts. I just get the message "you've already flagged this post". While this could be fixed, I think in most cases the user undeleting the post is the wrong action (there's a chance he may have fixed the post as I've seen in one case) and I think the post should automatically pick up a flag upon undeletion so that the mods can review it.

Comment: The problem is that users can undelete posts deleted by mods. I don't think that that should be allowed. If a post was bad enough to be flagged and deleted I think that any improvements should be in a new post.

Comment: Had you flagged that post before?

Comment: @Jon These are from my flag history, so yes. This is naturally the source of the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Once a flag is cleared from the mod queue, the same post cannot be re-flagged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61916/once-a-flag-is-cleared-from-the-mod-queue-the-same-post-cannot-be-re-flagged)