# If my flag auto-expired after 48 hours, can I flag the question or answer again?

Tags: discussion, flags

In this case:

I flagged a post as spamming/offensive, but in the past 48 hours fewer than 5 users flagged it, so the flag expired.

Can I flag the question or answer again?

From the description of "flag expiration": [Is there any way to remove Offensive flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work)

> "as offensive flags expire after 48 hours if the thresholds aren't reached."

Comment: How do you know that the flag expired? It's more likely that the flag was dismissed by a moderator. Can you check your [flag weight](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-weight/289558/) to see what it says about that particular flag?

Comment: If you're asking Cody, you *can* see that it says valid/invalid, but I've never seen 'expired'.  That said, it's never taken more than 24 hours for a mod to note my flag.  So, Roy, I don't think you need to worry about a flag expiring...

Comment: @M.Tibbits: Right, I'm not implying that the flag history will ever say "expired". My suspicion is that the flag didn't actually expire, but rather that it was either dismissed as invalid by a moderator, or dismissed as valid but no action was taken. I asked the asker to check his flag weight and report back.

Comment: I believe that since his flag weight is below 100, (currently 95), then the flag must've been invalid.  I've had a couple flags marked as valid(+10) where *I believe* the mod took no action as a result.

Comment: As of about 1 July 2011, ["once a mod has attended to your previous flag, you may then flag a post again,"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61916/once-a-flag-is-cleared-from-the-mod-queue-the-same-post-cannot-be-re-flagged/97090#97090) according to Jarrod (a dev)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything under the [Faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) about flags expiring.  That said, for all practical purposes, they never do because we've got such good mods here.  :O)

Comment: As it happens, I currently have two flags sitting in the queue, but they've both been there about an hour.  If you click this [flag-weight](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-weight/157773) link or the link in your profile, which @Cody suggested, you'll be able to view the status of your flags (Note, of course, that this link is site specific.)

Comment: I've had flags sit for many hours at a stretch. Usually after doing a lot of "not an answer" flagging through search results, then I'll see a couple dozen get cleared out quickly by the same moderator, then the rest are left to sit. I have to assume it's because they can only take so much before they have to find a stiff drink.