# Re-flagging a post as spam

Tags: support, flags, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If my flag auto-expired after 48 hours, can I flag the question or answer again?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97848/if-my-flag-auto-expired-after-48-hours-can-i-flag-the-question-or-answer-again)

I've just asked [this question](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/740/13085) on GameDev's Meta about handling spam flags. From [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/167443), I know that flags disappear after 48 hours if the requisite 6 flags are not reached. Considering GameDev's relatively low traffic, and the fact that the posts have been sitting around for between 7 months and a year, I expect that to be the case. In the case that that happens, are the (fewer than 6) users who flagged the post as spam able to again flag the post as spam? Or will 6 NEW users need to flag the post?

Additionally, what happens when the flags expire? Do they go away silently, or is there some notification to moderators that a post's spam flags have expired?

Comment: Somewhere here on meta, I'm sure I saw a mod said that they can see old expired flags on posts.  But, I doubt that they get a notice (or should) when flags expire.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Good catch - I didn't find it because I was searching specifically with the word "spam"